# What is the purpose of header in the C# webclient object

Tags: c#, web

What is the purpose of header in the C# webclient object? Why we use this property?

Comment: How much do you understand about HTTP?

Answer (score 1):

It allows you to set an HTTP request header that will be sent along the request. For example if the server side script expects the `User-Agent` header you could set it like this:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.52 Safari/536.5";
    string result = client.DownloadString("http://www.google.com");
}
```

There are many HTTP headers that you could read about in the [HTTP protocol](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) specification.

Comment: Then what is the purpose of setting http header when downloading?

Comment: The purpose is that the HTTP protocol expects some common headers to be sent along the request. Depending on how the server side script is implemented it allows for the client to pass some additional metadata about the request such as how the request values are encoded (`Content-Type` header), identify the client (`Cookies` header), ... I invite you to read more about the HTTP protocol as this is the basis for all web applications: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol